# angular 1.2.15 running concurrent loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to do this:

```
<tbody>
<tr class=“object.sibling[0]”>
<tr class=“object.sibling[1]”>
<tr class=“object.sibling[2]”>
<tr class=“object.sibling[2].child”>
<tr class=“object.sibling[2].child”>
<tr class=“object.sibling[3]”>
<tr class=“object.sibling[4]”>
```

however I am not sure how to keep track of two loops that are siblings.  I can easily do this:

```
<tbody> 

<tr class=“object.sibling[0]”>

<tr class=“object.sibling[1]”>

<tr class=“object.sibling[2]”>

<tr class=“object.sibling[3]”>

<tr class=“object.sibling[4]”>

<tr class=“object.sibling[2].child”>

<tr class=“object.sibling[2].child”>
```

but then the rows are out of order.

I found a solution that appears to work using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end that visually does exctally what I want but the extra empty rows needed to end the hg-repeat start loops messes up the table when users copy paste.

```
<tbody> 

<tr ng-repeat-start=“x in object.sibling”>

       <td class=“x”>

<tr ng-repeat-start=“y in x.child”>

       <td class=“Y”>

<tr ng-repeat-end=“”>

<tr ng-repeat-end=“”>
```

The problem is that the tr’s though they may represent children of siblings must all be on the same level as if that are all sibings.  I cannot figure out how to do this with angular 1.2.15.  How do I run two loops that keep track of each other that are not nested?

Comment: Honestly in this situation I would construct a flattened version of the array inside the directive that's rendering the table, and ng-repeat over that instead.

Comment: @DanielBeck I don't think it's necessary to complicate things with data flattening here. `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` should handle this scenario nicely IMO.

Comment: Certainly, I see your answer works @Agop, it's quite clever.   Personally I'd find a flattened array much easier to conceptualize and to extend (what about when the customer decides they want the table to be sortable too,  f'rinstance) but different strokes etc

Comment: @DanielBeck That's true. We'd need more information here to decide on an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, interesting scenario you've got. This should work:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="sibling in siblings"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="child in sibling.children"></tr>
```

The idea is to repeat two rows for each sibling, but the second row of each sibling is actually repeated for all of the sibling's children. So, in practice, the second row will only show up (and be repeated) if the sibling actually has children.

Here's a full example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.siblings = [
    {
      children: [
        {}, {}, {}
      ]
    },
    
    {},
    
    {
      children: [
        {}, {}
      ]
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <table ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="sibling in siblings">
      <td>Sibling {{$index}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="child in sibling.children">
      <td>Sibling child {{$index}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how there are no extra `<tr>` elements.

Comment: Thank you so much @Agop and DanielBeck this did the job.  I seems like the intended way to use start and end in this situation, using the dummy tr's is a bad hack.  And as far as filtering, yes this could be a future requirement but not within the bounds of this story.